# Importing ReactiveFormsModule in a nested imported module makes app crash

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm using a module with shared components that I use through the whole app, let's call it SharedModule. So until now everything worked perfectly but I added a component in SharedModule that uses a form, therefore I added ReactiveFormsModule to SharedModule imports. It's then when I get a confusing error in another module that imports SharedModule and that also has a form, and so it also imports ReactiveFormsModule. The error is the following:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
```

I've tried removing ReactiveFormsModule from the later module but then it shows an error saying that formgroup is an unknown attribute of form which translates into ReactiveFormsModule is necessary.

So my SharedModule looks like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, TranslateModule.forChild(), IonicModule, ReactiveFormsModule], <-- ReactiveFormsModule import
  declarations: [
    FooterComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    NoContentComponent,
    ModalLiveDeploy,
    PickerDirective,
    SelectComponent,
    InputComponent,
    RadioGroupComponent,
    CardComponent,
    SliderComponent,
    AccordionComponent,
    RadioComponent,
    CmbModalComponent <-- this is the one with the form in it
  ],
  entryComponents: [ModalLiveDeploy, CmbModalComponent],
```

And the other module, which is the one that shows the error, is something like this:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MainComponent], <-- this component has a form
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    TranslateModule.forChild(),
    SharedModule, <-- SharedModule which also imports ReactiveFormsModule 
    ReactiveFormsModule <-- ReactiveFormsModule import
  ]
})
```

Before adding the conflictive component to SharedModule and the ReactiveFormsModule it worked like a charm so that's why I think the error that's shown is not related. Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: Does your reactive form have a formGroup? The error literallys says you have formControls that do not have a parent formGroup - so can I just confirm your form setup has form groups?

Comment: Yes it does, in fact if I remove the conflicting component and the ReactiveForm import from SharedModule it works correctly

Comment: Alos, make sure you don't mix [(ngModule)] and formControlName in the same input. Always wrap your formControls inside a container such as <form [formGroup ]="TheNameOftheFormGroup">

Comment: Yes, I've checked just in case but I've not mixed ngModel and formControlName in any input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the error, in case this help anyone in the future:

So the problem was I was actually using the formControlName attribute without using a formGroup but it was in an old component from SharedModule not in the new one. It didn't raise any flags before because I wasn't importing ReactiveFormsModule in SharedModule, once I did so it crashed, the thing is the error trace pointed to a different module, one where I was using the component with said error, that was what was driving me crazy.

So summing up, if you add ReactiveFormsModule to a module and all of a sudden you see an error like this make sure you check every component, even the ones you haven't modified in a while.

Comment: It also helped me to go with "npm update" which gave me a better error message.